# Magento contact form not working

Tags: magento, contact-form

I am a rookie with Magento so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I just moved a Magento site from one server to another. Followed all the steps of changing base url in databse, .htaccess and all other stuff. Site is live and working fine on the new server.

There are a couple of problems though.

1. On contact us form, when I submit it just redirects back to the same page, all the details are removed and no emails are sent. This is the main problem.
2. I am not sure if this has some relation for the first problem but when I log into backend and go to Contact Page static block, the content box is missing like this:
   [image]

   and I see these errors in console.

   ```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL fckeditor.html:58
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCKBrowserInfo is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:128
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCKConfig_LoadPageConfig is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:167
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCKTools is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:179
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCK_ContextMenu_Init is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:198
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCKLang is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:206
   Uncaught ReferenceError: FCKBrowserInfo is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:334
   Uncaught ReferenceError: InitializeAPI is not defined fckeditor.html?InstanceName=block_content&Toolbar=Default:214
   ```

I am really not sure how to even start troubleshooting this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @Mahan - version 1.3.2.1

Comment: try to use the newer magento versions, the latest is 1.8 ithink

Comment: That is the whole problem here. Another developer made this site and now I am not sure if he has tampered with any of the core files or not. Don't want to take the risk of updating it without knowing what I  am stepping into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this file `\js\fontis\fckeditor\editor\fckeditor.html`. It is trying to echo some javascript from php but spaces were getting the the way. 
Starting from line 87

```
                document.body.innerHTML = '\

                <div style="border: 1px red solid; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: red; padding:10px;">\

                    <p>\

                        <b>Your browser security settings don\'t allow FCKeditor to be opened from\
```

continued... this was messing up the javascript. I removed all the spaces make it into a single line string and it worked.

Hope it helps!